# Joint probability distribution from a linear combination

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ which summed together give another random variable $X + Y = Z$. I also have the probability distributions for both (i.e $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ ).

Given that I know $X$ and $Y$ are independent, their probability distributions is it possible to work out the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$ ( $f_{XZ} (x,z)$) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X, Y$ are independent, we know that $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. In this case the change of variables is straightforward, just replace $y$ with $z - x$. So the joint density would be $f_{X,Z}(x, z) = f_X(x) f_Y(z - x)$. [You can find out more about changing variables in a probability density function on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).